# excel conditional formatting validate date

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I try to evaluate if a cell contains a valid date. If the content is not a valid date, the cell should be colored red. I want to do this without vb. On SO i got told, this is possible using only conditional formatting

Here is my try:

[image: wer das liest ist doof]

This doesn't work. I think the formular is fine, because i get no error message, but still no success.

---

Another try was to use Highlight Cells Rules and depending on a date occurring.

[image: hoch vom turm, kackt der wurm]

But here i can only use specific rules, like date is from this week, or this month, or past week. I can not say is a valid date or is a date between X and Y.

[image]

Any ideas how i can achieve my goal to set background-color of cells with invalid date-formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that 31.12.1899 is not a reconized date in Excel.
An excel date is a number and it starts with 0 = `00.01.1900`

So if you exchange your `31.12..1899` by `01.01.1900` your formula will work.

Comment: And, to make things the same, he should change the `>` to `>=` in the CF formula.  Oh, and `1 = 1 Jan 1900`

Comment: The problem seems to be the "AND". When i only use one of the terms without the and-concatinition it works.

Comment: Ok, my fault... i have a german version of excel. I have to write "und" instead of "and"...